# How do I know how many posts I've edited?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I see how many posts have I edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91878/where-can-i-see-how-many-posts-have-i-edited)

Apologies if this is a duplicate or very obvious, but I was wondering how do I find out how many posts I've edited/corrected on Stackoverflow and similar sites.  Is there a way to tell?

Comment: In short, no. There are some less accurate ways to do it with the data dump, but it will miss many edits.

Comment: As a temporary solution, here is a list of the edits you made that are still in effect http://statoverflow.com/sandbox/?q=SELECT%20Id,%20Title,%20LastEditDate%20FROM%20posts%20WHERE%20LastEditorUserId=82865%20AND%20OwnerUserId!=82865%20ORDER%20BY%20LastEditDate%20LIMIT%20500

Comment: Just curious, why would you need to know the number?

Comment: Presumably to see how close to the badge you are? ;)

Comment: @Ian: Or you can just ask for the count: http://statoverflow.com/sandbox/?q=SELECT%20Id,%20Title,%20LastEditDate%20FROM%20posts%20WHERE%20LastEditorUserId=82865%20AND%20OwnerUserId!=82865%20ORDER%20BY%20LastEditDate%20LIMIT%20500

Answer (score 28):

I keep track of mine on my <strike>cell</strike> livingroom wall:

[image: Tally marks on stone wall]

Answer (score 18):

Data explorer query (sadly way out of date right now):

https://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/s/1024/how-many-edits-have-i-made-and-how-much-more-until-i-earn-the-badges

Disclaimer: I am not the author. **Warning: Seems to run pretty slowly on StackOverflow**

More info:

- Seems to be based on [this explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79054/copy-editor-with-too-few-revisions/80260#80260) by waffles.
- Summary: **1 edit** is a post that you do not own, that you made an edit to either the title or body. (In other words, tags don't count, multiple edits don't count, your posts don't count).

Comment: I don't this query is correct, it gives me 0 for my user, and I've edited more than one post.

Comment: I get a 0 as well.

Comment: @BookOfZeus Make sure that you have the correct site selected. Also use your numeric UserID.

Comment: I can't switch the site to StackOverflow

Answer (score 11):

There's a tab in the Users page that shows edit counts, though it isn't clear to me yet what kind of edits are included in this count:

https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all&search=Jon

There's also this pair of queries, if you're interested in seeing your edit count in terms of progress toward badges:

- https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qt/5157/how-many-edits-have-I-made
- https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/5117/how-many-edits-until-strunk-white

Comment: It includes self-edits, so unless you are very aware of your ratio of editing own/other posts - this is a broad brush guide at best.

Comment: It probably includes all edits as well so multiple edits to the same post would count for that score whereas they don't count towards the S&W and Copy Editor badges.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell whether you've edited less than 100 or whether you've edited 100 or more by noticing whether you've got the Strunk & White badge.  After that, though, there is no reliable method of telling (that I know of).