# Copy Editor with too few revisions?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, edit-badges

I just earned the Copy Editor badge on Stack Overflow, but I don't think I have 600 edits!  On my profile, under "Activity > Revisions," I only have fourteen pages of edits, each of which has 30 edits on it.  That's less than 450 edits.  Did I somehow get this badge prematurely?

Or do not all edits show under "Activity > Revisions?"  Or is this a bug?

Comment: Just take your cookie and be happy!!!  Earning badges is what it's all about, who cares how its done?

Comment: @CrazyEddie templatetypedef is not complaining about it, they're trying to help out by reporting what looks like a bug. :)

Comment: Happened to me too today on askubuntu.com. Reading [this description](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399), I definitely got it without meeting the requirements.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

We counted "title" edits and "body" edits as distinct entities. This badge was awarded to users with 600 cumulative "title" or "body" edits.

Clearly this is not intuitive or right so I made some adjustments.

`Strunk & White` and `Copy Editor` now only count posts, provided:

- The post is not deleted
- You do not own the post

We only count an one "edit" per post, it does not matter if you edit the title or body multiple times.

To compensate for the stricter requirements we reduced the thresholds:

- `Copy Editor` requires **500** posts to be edited (as opposed to 600)
- `Strunk & White` requires **80** posts to be edited (as opposed to 100)

Comment: Interesting.  Could you post the list of people who would lose this?  I think 'revision guids' is the most correct implementation.

Comment: @jjnguy ... you could play with the results here: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/93545/

Comment: @jjunguy on second thoughts I may be able to fix this

Comment: Interesting - I have 21 pages of those revisions but no Copy Editor badge. I must've edited the same posts way too much (in fact, I did). Must edit harder!

Comment: @Waffles, interesting change.  How do the numbers differ now?

Comment: @jjnguy - about 30 lost "copy editor" ... about 200 or so lost "strunk & white"

Comment: Ah so retags don't count as an "edit".

Comment: @Jeff ... no they do not

Comment: @waffles - Is an edit counted towards the required "500 posts" if your edit is reverted, rolled back, or overwritten? Ie. if I were to make an edit and the OP went in and re-edited it (removing my edits). This happens a lot for grammar clean up sadly.