# Copy editor badge query vs. docs

Tags: support

(Possible dupe, though I haven't seen the mis-match explicitly mentioned.)

[Badge page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/223/copy-editor) says 500 posts, [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/metasuperuser/s/511/progress-towards-editor-badges) says 600.

If nothing else, which is right? Just curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The badge page is maintained by Stack Exchange itself.  It's official.  The query descriptions, on the other hand, are filled in by whoever makes the query, which could be anyone.

The requirements *used* to be 600, but [were changed to 500 in February](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79054/copy-editor-with-too-few-revisions/80260#80260)(HT:animuson).  When in doubt, trust the badges page (or a relevant meta post from an employee).

Comment: Ah. Yeah, a different query had 500 hard-coded in, and did some math to figure out which edits counted (which dropped my edit count way down from what's reported in the "Users>Editors" info).

Comment: [It was changed from 600 to 500 in February.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80260/141525)

Comment: @DaveNewton This badge is one that is currently *very* hard to track progress for.  I think your best indicator would be the review page (assuming you already have Strunk & White, but otherwise why bother?).

Comment: @Dave Newton: Your current progress towards the Copy Editor and Electorate badges are now tracked in the /review section below your review stats. You probably need the Strunk & White badge to view those (along with your review stats). There are other restrictions for which edits are counted as well, see the link above.

Comment: @animuson and atJohn Oh, crap, that's right--I totally forgot I saw that the other day :/ Good grief :(