# Editing badges delay

Tags: discussion, badges, edit-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What kind of edits contribute to the editor badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges)
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

Is there a delay on the `Strunk & White` badge ?

Just to make sure I get it right, everytime I get a `+2 rep Edit` it counts  ?

Comment: No, it needs to be edits for *unique posts*. Editing the same post twice doesn't count.

Comment: There are more restrictions, see [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397)

Comment: Ok well let's say I never edit the same post twice and I count everytime I got a +2 for editing

Comment: Also see [What kind of edits contribute to the editor badges?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/442)

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk: Read the badge list. Edits to the same post multiple times, edits to your own posts, and edits which only change tags all do not count. So no, going by how many times you've gotten a +2 is not at all an accurate measurement. You can still [go here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers) to see your progress towards the badge (at the right), until the new beta review goes into effect.

Comment: And lastly see [Copy Editor with too few revisions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79054)/

Comment: @animuson I never edit twice a post, I never edit tags only and editing my own post does not give a +2. There must be a delay then

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk: or some of the posts you've edited have been deleted.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk: Yes, most all badges have a delay. In general, badges are awarded sometime between 1 second and 24 hours after the criteria are met (if you wanted a timeframe).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah that could be possible I didn't know they didn't count anymore. thanks

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers; I am reasonably sure you'll see your progress listed there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you were right. I added an answer

Comment: @animuson that page doesn't show anything accurate for me. [Here is what it currently says](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Tn3c0.png) (but look at my badge list). I don't know where it gets those numbers but I don't think they're mine.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: If you already have the badges, it obviously doesn't display your progress towards them. ;) For users which don't have them, it will display their progress towards Strunk & White, Copy Editor, and Electorate.

Comment: @animuson understood, but the numbers should still be accurate. What do the numbers in my screen shot even mean?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Those numbers are for the actions you've done *from within the review panel*, not the numbers for each of those actions you've done throughout the entire site.

Comment: @animuson I still don't believe they're accurate, unless they're only counting the things I've done in the review panel since the new review panel was launched.

Answer (score 0):

I read all your comments and I thanks you. I can now confirme it's a delay with this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Badges are awarded by the SE software during batch processes, which occur at unspecified times.