# How I check the exact composition of the edits that I made

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, badges, edit-badges

I did about 500 plus edits on stackoverflow, but I didn't know that how many my edits are of tag, title, of grammar, of formatting and how many edit I made on old post? and how many edit I made on new post.

I completed 500 plus successful edit but didn't able to get gold badge of `Copy Editor` 
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: yes after 500 edits, now on every edit I have made and after its approved I 'm not getting any +2 rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check how many edits are needed before you can get the editing badges using [this Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/28666/how-many-edits-have-i-made-and-how-much-more-until-i-earn-the-badges). In your particular case, it looks like a few of your edits were to the same post multiple times. According to waffles's [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80260/175498) on the subject:

> Strunk & White and Copy Editor now only count posts, provided:
>
> - The post is not deleted
> - You do not own the post
>
> We only count an one "edit" per post, it does not matter if you edit the title or body multiple times.

In addition, it looks like only retagging a post [does not count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79054/copy-editor-with-too-few-revisions/80260#comment196564_80260) as an edit.
With these guidelines, it appears you only have 361 edits eligible for the Copy Editor badge.

Comment: Indeed; _Copy Editor_ says "Edited 500 posts", not "Made 500 edits"

Comment: ohh I see, so please tell me one thing now, why I am not getting +2 reputation now on successful edit.

Comment: @Irfan - You can only receive a maximum of 1000 reputation from accepted suggested edits (or 500 suggested edits). Like what Jonathan mentioned, you've made at least 500 edits, but for the badge, you need to edit 500 _posts_. Still, getting +1000 from suggesting edits is pretty nice!

Comment: @ChrisForrence ok thanks, one last thing please tell me now all the other edit I will made I am unable to get +2 points, or after some specific amount of edits done I again getting point?

Comment: @Irfan - The 1000 reputation from suggested edits is a lifetime limit; once you reach that limit, you won't be able to gain any more reputation points from suggesting edits. At this point, you might want to look at giving a few good answers/asking good questions so that you can reach 2000 reputation and gain the ability to edit posts directly.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know of a way to determine how each of them are of each type, but you can see [a list of your edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3275134/irfan?tab=activity&sort=revisions) under the revisions sub-tab of the activity tab of your profile.

Comment: so what is the reason be-hide that still I not got my copy editor badge.